# dictionary creation from pyodbc row is throwing error

Tags: python, dictionary

my dictionary is in the format `{'"k1"': ' "v1"', '"k2"': ' "v2"', '"k3"': ' "v3"'}`.
How can i remove those extra single quotes?

I tried replacing it using replace function, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You could strip spaces and double quotes from the keys and values using a dictionary comprehension;

```
> new_dict = {k.strip(' "'):v.strip(' "') for k,v in old_dict.items()}

> new_dict
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

- [`replace()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/) - it returns a copy of the string where all occurrences of a substring are replaced with another substring.
- [`strip()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-strip-2/) - To remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.

**Ex.**

```
myDict = {'"k1"': ' "v1"', '"k2"': ' "v2"', '"k3"': ' "v3"'}

result = {key.replace('"','').strip(): val.replace('"','').strip() for key, val in myDict.items() }

print(result)
```

**O/P:**

```
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
```